# Validation model without a table in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, model

I have a controller called **messages_controller**

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  ...
end
```

and the form for send messages on users' email addresses:

```
  = form_for [@user, @message], :validate => true do |f|
    = f.text_field :subject, :maxlength => 100
    = f.text_area :body, :placeholder => 'Your message...'
    = f.submit 'Send message'
```

I would like to validate this form, so I created this model - **message.rb**:

```
class Message
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  extend ActiveModel::Naming

  attr_accessor :name, :body

  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_presence_of :body

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    attributes.each do |name, value|
      send("#{name}=", value)
    end
  end

  def persisted?
    false
  end
end
```

However, when I run the app, I get the following error message:

```
undefined method `reflect_on_association' for Message:Class
```

What's wrong in my structure of the form - controller - model?

I am not very experienced here, so I would be very grateful for every advice.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You're using a nested resource path in your `form_for` but you haven't told the Message that it `belongs_to :user`. Since it's tableless you won't be able to. Remove the `[@user, @message]` from your `form_for`. If you still need the user id add it with a `hidden_field`.